# PHP Video Manipulation with dynamically loaded images in video or a javascript overlay like youtube ads

Tags: php, video

I have a requirement which I have been unable to find any solutions too, not many pointers exists on the internet either, couple of video editors I asked are of the opinion that it might not be possible.

Lets say I have a video and I am uploading it to a website, i want a dynamic image to load inside the video at the end of every 30secs, and if possible, then not really sure if I can upload these videos on Youtube or Vimeo either?

Any heads up will be great, I am totally lost here.

Comment: You can´t manipulate video´s directly with PHP. You´ll need to call `exec` to a third party library something like `FFMPEG`

Comment: You could alternatively show something on top of the video, but then that might risk concealing a part that users wish to watch. Perhaps that could be integrated with JavaScript start/stop of the video - there might be a JS library for this. That might have buffering issues though, so prototyping would be necessary.